# Code not stopping even with while loop PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

Im trying to get the user to input 8 times,and after that I'm printing out the array. But the while loop doesn't seem to be stopping for some reason ? Here's my code:

```
from numpy import*
t = array([int()]*200)

def premier(n):
    b = True
    for i in range(2,n//2):
        if n%i==0:
            b = False
    return(b)

def quadruplets(t):
    k=1
    while k < 8:
        
        for i in range(0,len(t),4):
            
            t[i] = int(input("Give t of I: "))
            if premier(t[i]) == False:
                t[i] = int(input("Don't make this harder than it already is: "))
            t[i+1]=t[i]+2
            t[i+2]=t[i]+6
            t[i+3]=t[i]+8
            print(t)
            k+=1
            print("your k is now: ",k)
        
quadruplets(t)
print("your final table is: ",t)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the numpy module but you're not actually utilizing any of its features, you're simply creating an array of ints using a list comprehension. Second, your while loop is never going to end because you are incrementing the value of k inside the for loop, which means that k will always be less than 8. You should increment k after the for loop instead.

Here's how you could fix your code:

```
from numpy import array

def premier(n):
    b = True
    for i in range(2,n//2):
        if n%i==0:
            b = False
    return(b)

def quadruplets(t):
    k = 0
    while k < 8:
        for i in range(0,len(t),4):
            t[i] = int(input("Give t of I: "))
            if premier(t[i]) == False:
                t[i] = int(input("Don't make this harder than it already is: "))
            t[i+1]=t[i]+2
            t[i+2]=t[i]+6
            t[i+3]=t[i]+8
        k += 1
        print("your k is now: ",k)
        
t = array([int()]*200)
quadruplets(t)
print("your final table is: ",t)
```

However, I would recommend simplifying your code further by removing the while loop and using a for loop instead, since you already know that you want to iterate 8 times:

```
from numpy import array

def premier(n):
    b = True
    for i in range(2,n//2):
        if n%i==0:
            b = False
    return(b)

def quadruplets(t):
    for k in range(8):
        for i in range(0,len(t),4):
            t[i] = int(input("Give t of I: "))
            if premier(t[i]) == False:
                t[i] = int(input("Don't make this harder than it already is: "))
            t[i+1]=t[i]+2
            t[i+2]=t[i]+6
            t[i+3]=t[i]+8
        print("your k is now: ",k+1)
        
t = array([int()]*200)
quadruplets(t)
print("your final table is: ",t)
```

Lastly, you should consider giving your variables more descriptive names to make your code easier to read and understand.

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help. But it still does not work